# Yml config file in RoR 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is my config.yml file. In fact user_id, api_key and shared_secret are the same for each environment (development, test or production).

```
development:
  user_id: '1234'
  api_key: '1234'
  shared_secret: '43243'
  some_dev_data: 'fdsfdsfd'
test:
   some_test_data: 'rytr'

production:
   some_prod_data: 'hgf'
```

How do I make them independent from current environment? Or how to share them between all environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use anchors to pull out shared data:

```
shared_stuff: &shared
  user_id: '1234'
  api_key: '1234'
  shared_secret: '43243'

development:
  <<: *shared
  some_dev_data: 'fdsfdsfd'

test:
  <<: *shared
  some_test_data: 'rytr'

production:
  <<: *shared
  some_prod_data: 'hgf'
```

Your values under `shared_stuff` are given the anchor name `shared` which you can then pull into your different environments.